# Problem with DateTime toString()

Tags: c#

Hy!

The DateTime.toString() gives 12 hours more back as in the debugger written.

Do i need CultureInfo?

(in austria we are used to count from 0 - 24 for the hours)

thx

My Code:

```
DateTime dtime = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1, Convert.ToInt32(tim2.hour), Convert.ToInt32(tim2.minute), Convert.ToInt32(tim2.second));
label2.Text = dtime.ToString    ("hh:mm:ss.F");
```

Debugger:

```
+       dtime   {01.01.1900 00:05:48}   System.DateTime

+       label2.Text "12:05:48"  string
```

Comment: @Drackir: He wants to show the date using 24hour format. The code gave him away

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hh` is a 12 hour format (i.e. 0:05 is 12:05 AM). It sounds like you want to use `HH` instead, which is a 24 hour format:

`label2.Text = dtime.ToString    ("HH:mm:ss.F");`

Relevant documentation for the formatters can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

In [custom date format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), `hh` displays the hour using 12-hour clock. If you want to have 24-hour clock, use `HH`.

Answer (score 0):

00:05:48 would be 12 Midnight.  If you want your time formated with a 24 hour time, then you should use `dtime.ToString('HH:mm:ss.F");`